# Syntax error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having issue with VBA code in Excel.
Here's my code

```
Sub generateMatrix(size, lowerbound, upperbound)
    For i = 1 To size
        For j = 1 To size
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Sub taskOne()
    generateMatrix(5, -100, 50)
End Sub
```

As you can see, `generateMatrix()` is being used to return matrix of random integer numbers to active worksheet, that uses arguments: `size`, `lowerbound` and `upperbound`.
In `taskOne()` sub I'm using that `generateMatrix()`, specifying arguments correctly, but when I run that `taskOne()` sub, I get `Compiler error: Syntax error` and somewhy it highlights `Sub taskOne()` line as if the issue would be in that line...

What would be the reason of such issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define a `Sub` rather than a function. Try this:

```
Sub taskOne()
    generateMatrix 5, -100, 50
End Sub
```

You could also do this:

```
Sub taskOne()
    Call generateMatrix(5, -100, 50)
End Sub
```

Comment: Suprisingly, but that worked. Strange way to run Sub in other Sub. Thanks :)